# whats the difference between responseBody and Serialization

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring Framework,i am using responseBody annotation and serialization,i learned that responseBody is for HttpMessageConverts,it will return the output to view Resolver and serialization will convert the data in to byte stream and transfer it using version Id and header,here i have a question that, whats the difference between this two ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Serialization`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java) is a computer science concept that describes how a data structure can be broken down and stored. `Deserialization` is the reverse, taking a stored format and converting it back into a data structure.

[`@ResponseBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) is an annotation that Spring MVC uses on `@RequestMapping` methods. It tells the `DispatcherServlet` to take the return value of your handler method and, using an [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html), serialize it and write it directly to the HTTP response `OutputStream`.

See the javadoc of `HttpMessageConverter` for a list of implementation classes. You can write `byte[]`, `String`, `InputStream`, `Resource` objects directly to the stream. There also exist `HttpMessageConverter` classes for converting any object returned by the handler method to JSON or XML.